# Cartesian Product and Relations

Tags: relations

If a relation is defined between the first coordinate and the second coordinate of an ordered pair(aRb), then how come R = {(1,2),(5,6)} is a relation ? How can there be more than 1 ordered pair in a relation ?

Comment: Not very clear... $R = \{ (a, b) \mid a \in A \text { and } b \in B \} \subseteq A \times B$ is a relation. $R$ is a *set* of pairs.

Comment: You need a better understanding of what a relation is.  You use relations in your everyday life... you just might not know it by those words.  Consider for example the words "*hello world*" and the relation between each of these words and a letter in those words.  $\{(hello, h),(hello, e),(hello, l),(hello,o),(world,w),(world,o),(world,r),(world,l),(world,d)\}$ would be the representation of this relation.  "*How can there be more than 1 ordered pair in a relation?*" because there are many words and because there are many letters per word...  *Of course* there are multiple pairs.

Comment: Do not confuse and conflate *an element of the relation* with *the relation itself*.

Comment: Relations in everyday life: "*Who lives near me?*"  "*Who is related to who?*"  "*Who is taller than who?*"  "*What company owns what product?*"  "*What is the meaning of words?*"...  In math we try to generalize and formalize such concepts.

Answer (score 0):

A relation on $A$ is defined as any subset of $A\times A$. As such, $\{(1,2), (5,6)\}$ is a relation on $\mathbb R$ (and on $\mathbb Q$, and $\mathbb N$, for that matter). In other words, a relation is a *set of pairs*, not just a single pair.

In your particular relation, you have $1R2$ and you have $5R6$, because writing $aRb$ is just shorthand for saying $(a,b)\in R$.